VSCode source control diff view - ignore metadata/outputs
When dealing with .ipynbs and comparing before committing from the source control tab, it shows metadata and output differences:

I really don't care about these; I only want to know if the Input has changed.
Is there a way to hide these changes permanently? In a setting/config? I know I can temporarily hide/fold them, but this is manual and isn't scalable.
